# Issue with Django Channels. Not able to recieve the message in javascript nor print the message in python terminal

Tags: python, django, redis, django-channels

I am adding the django channels, where I want to get the progress of each task in for loop that it is being done or not and update the task progress accordingly on the frontend,

My views.py has a view as,

```
@login_required
def view_create_job_bulk(request):

    """
        Author : Aroosh Ahmad
        Modified Date : Jan-02-2024
        Modified By : None
        Description : Written to automate the Job creation process.
    """

    if config_operator.debug_flag:
        printf("In Create job Bulk View")
    # Fetching user details
    username = request.user.username
    user_id = request.user.user_id
    user_role = request.user.role
    context = {
        'username': username,
        'user_role': user_role,
    }

    if config_operator.debug_flag:
        printf(f"View create job Called by user id:{user_id} with role:{user_role}")

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:

        # Getting data details
        file = request.FILES.get('file')

        data = pd.read_csv(file)

        file_paths = data[1:]["File Link Local PC"]
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

        print("Channel Layer is: ", channel_layer)

        for i, filepath in enumerate(file_paths, start=1):
            print(f"File path is : {filepath}")

            async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})

            channel_layer.group_send(
                'notifications_group',
                {'type': 'send.notification', 'message': f'Iteration {i}'}
            )

            time.sleep(10) 

        response_data = {'message': 'post request complete!!'}
        return JsonResponse(response_data)


    return render(request, 'create_bulk_job.html', context)
```

The asgi.py is as follow

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from ttsf.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ttsf.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": URLRouter(
        websocket_urlpatterns
    ),
})
```

The consumer is,

```
import json
import asyncio
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        print("Connected channels")
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        # You can process the received message here
        print(f"Received message from client: {text_data}")
        # You might want to broadcast this message to others if needed
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': 'Received your message'}))

    async def send_notification(self, message):
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': message}))
        print(f"Message sent: {message}")
```

I am able to connect but the message is not recieved in the js but the console for connect works,

```
console.log('WebSocket URL:', 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/notifications/');

var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/notifications/');

socket.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection established');
};

socket.onmessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    // Check if the message type is 'send.notification'
    if (data.type === 'send.notification') {
        var notificationMessage = data.message;

        // Perform actions based on the received message
        console.log(notificationMessage);

        // Update your frontend UI or trigger any other logic here
    }
};

socket.onclose = function (e) {
    console.error('WebSocket closed unexpectedly');
};

socket.onerror = function(err) {
  console.log("WebSocket encountered an error: " + err.message);
  console.log("Closing the socket.");
  chatSocket.close();
}
```

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow already, I tried to reinstall the channels and use the redis server instead of Daphne, it made the connection successfult but the message is not being sent or recieved even in django application.